# Can a Public Careers CV Be an "Associated Account"?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, association

If you have a public Careers CV, it would be awesome if you could link it to your SO/SF/SU/Meta Account, and it'd be listed either at the bottom of the Name/Member Since/.../Age Column *or* on the Associated Accounts section (although that's really "below the fold").

Yes, I know you can put it in your about me box, or as your "website", but you could say the same thing for associated accounts.  It'd be a good point of integration (although low on the priority list).